# Issue while executing the multi-layer commands on windows

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, tcsh

The below is executing **on windows**:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe  -c "echo abc; echo 1 ; c:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe -c "c:/cygwin/bin/tcsh.exe echo def; pwd "  "
```

Running the above command, and getting the output as:

```
abc
1
[PPP@machine1 ...Users/PPP]$
```

Desired Output:

```
 abc
 1
 def
 C:\Users\PPP
```

In all, I want the commands under tcsh to also work (In above command, it is "echo def; pwd"). How can I have the progress on it?

Comment: Can you put everything from `"echo abc...` in `test.sh` and run `C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe test.sh` ? With that, it's much easier to handle quotes.

Comment: I see a problem of wrong sequence of ". Additional why you run the program from CMD instead of Mintty Terminal ?

Comment: In this type of situation, I tend to write a script or two, instead of trying to fight with windows handling of quotes.

Comment: Why do you want to execute `tcsh` with `bash -c`?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano, That's the requirement.

Comment: @matzeri, what is the right sequence for quotes? Any sampler for understanding this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you really want to nest multiples calls as
`bash -> bash -> tcsh`

A possible way to do it

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe  -c "echo abc; echo 1 ; c:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe -c 'c:/cygwin64/bin/tcsh.exe -c \"echo def \" ; pwd '  "
```

and the output on my W10 CMD is

```
abc
1
def
/cygdrive/c/Users/marco
```

but it is horrible and a lot is superfluous.
Still horrible but simplified, using the first call as login-shell

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe  -l -c "echo abc; echo 1 ; bash -c 'tcsh.exe -c \"echo def \" ; pwd '  "
```

and the output is

```
abc
1
def
/home/marco
```

In general I miss the need of all the nested calls, and writing a simple shell scripts with all command should be enough.
Also using a batch file like

--- prova.bat -----

```
@echo off

C:
chdir C:\cygwin64\bin

set A=%1
bash --login  -c "/usr/bin/echo $(cygpath $A)"
pause
```

--- end --------